# how can i change websocket request headers Origin,in a

Tags: websocket, request-headers

**I want to change my websocket request header Origin.But i do not know how to do.
it is javascript in browser, it runs in client but not server**

Comment: In what language are you coding?

Comment: javascript in browser. its client not server

Comment: maybe it could help if you put some example of your code